# After power outage, main user logs out before I can use it (16.04)

Tags: 16.04, login, crash

My 16.04 LTS system is configured with two users: me and a (non-admin) friend. After a recent neighborhood power outage, my user logs out before I can do anything. That is, I get the login (password) prompt and supply the correct password. Screen clears, top bar (indicator) appears with expected icons, unity launcher(?) bar appears with correct icons and hides. Then there's a "flash" (screen goes white for an instant then back to normal), then back to login screen. Once the top bar is visible, I can pull down menus etc, but don't have time for anything actually happen (e.g., if I select Thunderbird).

The other user logs in just fine. Guest session logs in just fine. I can log in to terminal (Ctrl-Alt-F1) as me just fine (as well as su to me from other logins). If I try to switch to me from other user or guest, it's the same as logging in normally (as described above).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, nevermind. I removed ~/.*auth* (well, I hid them in a new directory) and afterwards I could login just fine. I just didn't think I'd get this far if there was an authority issue. And somehow I missed the line in lightdm.log that reported authorization failure. Sorry to waste your time. :(

Comment: You didn't waste time with Q&A. But you can save time by taking your question off the "unanswered list" by clicking the check mark next to your answer.

Comment: I tried to, but it said I had to wait 24 hrs before picking my own answer. By then I'd forgotten about it. Sorry.

Comment: No worries on the delay... the important thing is the question shows as answered now.